# Can't change location that Laravel looks for PostgreSQL SSL certificate

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, ssl

I've installed pgsql and set up my Laravel config/database.php as follows:

```
'connection_name' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
    'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE_2'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'options' => [
        'sslcert' => '/some/special/path.crt',
    ],
    'schema' => 'public',
],
```

'connection_name' is located in the 'connections' section of `database.php`.

In artisan tinker I get the following error because it's still looking in the default location for the SSL certificate. I cannot get it to look in the right location for the cert.

```
>>> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
>>> DB::connection('connection_name')->getPdo()
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] root certificate file "/home/wes/.postgresql/root.crt" does not exist
Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.'
```

Comment: Why is ssl(root)cert inside 'options'?  Is that from the docs, or some tutorial?  I don't use laravel, but I would expect sslmode and sslrootcert to be peers, not at different levels.

Comment: I tried putting those options at the sibling level but I saw someone on Laracasts suggest the correct way for Postgres was to put those in an 'options' child.

Answer (score 1):

The root cert is set by "sslrootcert".  This is the certificate that signed the server's cert.

"sslcert" sets the client cert.  That is something different.

Comment: I tried that. I tried 'sslcert', 'sslrootcert', and 'PGSSLCERT'. Whatever I do it still tries to get the cert from ~/.postgresql/root.crt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I ran into this issue today. My solution was a combination of jjanes answer and comment. I had to set the variable at a higher level and also change to "sslrootcert"

```
       'pgsql' => [
           'driver' => 'pgsql',
           'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
           'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
           'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
           'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
           'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
           'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
           'charset' => 'utf8',
           'prefix' => '',
           'prefix_indexes' => true,
           'search_path' => 'public',
           'sslmode' => env('SSL_MODE'),        <-- this says "verify-ca"
           'sslrootcert' => env('PGSQL_SSL_CA') <-- this is fullpath
       ],
```

This worked when I used `php artisan migrate` on my PGSQL managed database on Digital Ocean.